# C# Winforms DateTimePicker Custom Formatted to Tenths of a Second / Default Selection to Seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, datetimepicker

My application currently uses the DateTimePicker custom formatted to display HH:mm:ss.

How can I format it so to allow for tenths of a second? 
My second question is that when I tab into the datetimepicker, the Hours section is selected first by default, is there anyway to change this so that seconds are selected first by default? I noticed that If you click the updown arrows without tabbing into the control the seconds section is selected by default.

Any experts on the datetimepicker out there? Or does anyone have an ideas on an alternative I can use to implement these features?

Below is a picture of how it is formatted as well as the properties:
[image: DateTimePickers]

[image: Properties]

Comment: You would have to make your own control, unfortunately. The DateTimePicker is very specific as to what it allows, and parts of a second are not included.

Comment: Do you have any good references for how to go about making my own datetimepicker type control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to force the `DateTimePicker` to display milliseconds, but it will be a painful experience. You are better off using a `MaskedTextBox`. You can download TimePicker.cs from sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/time-picker/

[image]

Here is some sample code:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Form f = new Form();
        var dp = new TimePicker("hh:mm:ss.f", true) { Location = new Point(100, 100) };
        dp.ByValue[2] = false;
        f.Controls.Add(dp);
        var bt1 = new Button { Text = "Now", Location = new Point(110, 130) };
        bt1.Click += delegate {
            dp.Value = DateTime.Now;
        };

        int k = 0;
        dp.ValueChanged += delegate {
            bt1.Text = "Now " + (k++);
        };
        f.Controls.Add(bt1);
        Application.Run(f);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! your code is SUPER helpful, but I am still tinkering with it to get it to work perfectly. Right now I am trying to tweak the way selection is handled and the way values are changed OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp events. I basically want it to mimic how things normally work on the datetimepicker, such that if I type in a single digit, it adds it to the "tens" place, however, I enter 2 digits it moves the first digit entered to the "ones" place. This is insanely trickky for me.

Comment: @user3653277 The `MaskedTextBox` control provides `InsertKeyMode`, but the only options are `Insert` or `Overwrite`. I think to do what you are asking would require intercepting the Key Down message (possibly by overriding the `WndProc`) method and then creating the text to mimic the `DateTimePicker` behavior. I'll look into it and see if it's possible.

Comment: Were you able to see if that was possible? I am a little out of my zone here, I have been trying to make it work manually, but it not going terribly well.

Comment: @user3653277 Still working on it, taking longer than expected.

Comment: is your timePicker still going okay?

Comment: @user3653277 Putting the control through more testing. Making sure inputting text is handled properly.

Comment: Just checking in, anything I can do to help?

Comment: Another project came up that requires a few days to finish. Sorry for the delay, I will definitely release the control as soon as possible.

Comment: Checking in again. Is there anyway I can finish up from where you are at if you don't have time to finish?

Comment: New code is updated. All source code files are in the "src" folder in the zip file. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, I cant wait to implement it. I will let you know :)

Comment: @user3653277 It might interest you that a clock drop down menu was added to the time picker.

Comment: Thank you again! I still have not had the time quite yet to implement this. I will very soon.

Comment: Sorry, about this question, i am new at this. I am finally able to implement this MaskedTextBox project you created. What is the best way to go about doing this? I was able to add the whole thing as a standalone project to my current solution, but should I be adding this specifically as a control or reference somehow? or am i doing it correctly?

Comment: There are two common ways to use a 3rd party project. Compile it into a DLL and then import the DLL. Or add the .cs files directly to your project. You can look at the `TimePickerMillisPanel` class inside the `MaskedTextBoxTestPanel.cs` file as an example on how to use the control.

Comment: I apologize, but am I missing something? When I open the solution file, many of the classes say they have been "Moved or deleted". In fact, MaskedTextBoxTestPanel.cs, Program.cs, and SpinControlTestPanel.cs are the only ones available. I looked at the code in the TimePickerMillisPanel class but I dont understand where the control even is to implement it.

Comment: @user3653277 They are all in the "/src/" folder in the zip file. You will need to remove the existing links that don't work and re-add them from the src folder. Limitation of trying to organize projects in Visual Studio.

Comment: I am determined to get this implemented :) thank you for all your continued help. I have sort of run into yet another problem. I decided to go ahead and compile the project into a DLL and import the DLL into my current solution. I added a reference to the "MaskedTextBoxLibrary" I created, but I cannot add it with a "using" statement because the library wont show up with intellisense.

Comment: @user3653277 Are you typing `using Opulos.Core.UI` ? If you can't see that namespace, it probably means the DLL is missing the files in the `/src/` folder. So in the `MaskedTextBoxLibrary` solution, check how many files it contains, should be 18.

Comment: that was it! I changed the default namespace of the dll when i imported into my project but I forgot that the namespaces of the actual project were still under Opulos. Thanks again! ... getting closer :)

Comment: So I am definitely making progress now! I have the "enchanced maskedtextbox" (as timepicker) control showing up on my form at runtime. I also tweaked it to properly obtain milliseconds. Now my question is how I can get the maskedtextbox control to work more closely to the normal timepicker. (I havent spent to much time looking yet). I see that you have a property "Keep Token Selected". This is the effect I want, however, if you try to select seconds, It selects both seconds and milliseconds. Seconds and milliseconds act as a single token almost. Is that by design? or can I change it?

Comment: @user3653277 Yes, it's possible to change and make them separate tokens. However, if they are two separate tokens, then typing "12.345" won't work. So the default is a combined token. To split them into two different tokens, at the top of the `TimePicker(...)` constructor, add the line `SplitChars = new [] { ':', '.' };`

Comment: perfect! I now have that implemented. The final I would like make would be the ability to have each token act as a tab stop. For instance, I noticed that when tabbing into the control, the "Hours" token is selected by default as the control's tabstop. If I press tab again, the next tab stop is on the "Hours" of the other TimePicker control I have on the form. Is there anyway to make each consecutive token a tabstop, such that for every tab press; Hours, mins, sec, then millisec are highlighted in that order?

Comment: @user3653277 The left and right arrows do that. However, if you want to use `Tab` and `Shift+Tab`, then in the `MaskedTextBox.cs` code, look at the `PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg)` method when `key == LEFT.` That will show you how to select tokens. However, you would probably need to have a special case that pressing the `Tab` key on the last token is not intercepted. Similarly, `Shift+Tab` on the first token is not intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

This could work

1. Add a DomainUpDown control
2. Add a bunch of datetimes that vary by .1 seconds and display them as strings formatted to show miliseconds. Your user can then click up and down to see .1 second deltas

   ```
       string dateString = "7/9/2015 9:32:45.126 AM";
       DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           dtPicker.Items.Add(dateValue.AddSeconds(.1*i).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
       }
   ```
3. If you want to let the user pick say the hour first and then generate your datetime deltas from there it won't work as well. You could create multiple numeric controls, but at that point you might want to go down the path of extending the datetime picker like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3579/Extended-DateTimePicker).